# Facebook event invite api returns true but the user does not recieve invite. Is this a bug?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am inviting users via API from the host of an event created by a fanpage on Facebook. I have tested with two host accounts. With the first the api works fine:

EVENT_ID/invited?user=USER_ID returns "true and the user is invited.

On the other account, the following happens:

EVENT_ID/invited?user=USER_ID returns "true but the user is not invited.

Both accounts have the same access token and are registered developer accounts. I have tried everything I can think of to no avail.

Has anyone had this issue?